# Ruby on Rails: How to define an extension and put it into a database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to modify following code in order to be able to write only the file extension into a database. Now I read the file_content_type, but I need only to know the extension (it doesn't matter for me that the extension can be changed) and to put it into a database. 
upload_file_name has an extension already, but I need to extract it and put it in the same database-table as a new row.

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20120731045929) do

  create_table "uploads", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "upload_file_name"
    t.string   "upload_content_type"
    t.string   "user"
    t.integer  "upload_file_size"
    t.datetime "upload_updated_at"
    t.datetime "created_at",          :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",          :null => false
  end
```

end

And it is possible somehow to save the file_name without an extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like it's from `schema.rb`.

Don't touch that one directly.

If you look under `/db/migrations` you'll have ruby files with messy looking file names. These are the ruby files that let you configure your database tables.

- First add a column in the database.

In the terminal, run `rails generate migration add_file_content_type_to_uploads file_content_type:string`

- In Upload.rb model file, add `file_content_type` to attr_accessible

`attr_accessible :file_content_type`

- To find the extension, you can use `File.extname`.

So maybe in your `create` method of uploads controller

```
def create
  ...
  @upload.file_content_type = File.extname(params[:upload_file_name])
  ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.
What if I need following: Before uploading files, user can select the files and view the name of the files to be uploaded. There is as well a select-menu , in roder to select the category of files,like "Home", "Work", "Outside","Travelling" and etc. How can I put the seleceted from the user Category in the database? How can I bind the category-option with a database?

Comment: ps. For the serie of files the user can chose only one category. and a select box is made with html <select>

Comment: There's a rails helper for select tag. Take a look at [options_for_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select)